# Does VB6 have the ability to "cast" an object as type "Printer"?

Tags: vb6, wmi

```
Private Function SelectAPrinter(myName As String) As Printer

Dim strComputer As String
Dim objWMIService As Object
Dim myPrinter As Object

strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set myPrinter = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Printer where Name = '" & myName & "'")

Set SelectAPrinter = myPrinter
  
End Function
```

so of course VB6 barks at me with "type mismatch" which is no surprise. I am attempting to set an object
(myPrinter) to type Printer.

I DO NOT Know how to finish this function.
IS THERE a method of "casting" an object to type Printer?

Comment: Let me answer the question of why not use the PRINTERS collection that vb6 has builtin?  The Answer is because there are literally 500+ redirects(many appear to be duplicates)  filling the clients Printers collection. WMI gets around that and allows me to build a list of printers - no redirects or duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not mind setting the default printer temporarily, then perhaps the following will work.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim saveme As String
    Dim yourprinter As Printer
    
    saveme = Printer.DeviceName
    
    Set yourprinter = SelectAPrinter("Canon iR-ADV C5045/5051 PCL5c")
    
    Debug.Print "selected", yourprinter.DeviceName ' Microsoft Print to PDF
    
    Call SelectAPrinter(saveme) ' restore default
    
    Debug.Print "restored", Printer.DeviceName
End Sub

Private Function SelectAPrinter(myName As String) As Printer
    
    Dim strComputer As String
    Dim objWMIService As Object
    Dim colInstalledPrinters As Object
    Dim myPrinter As Object
    
    strComputer = "."
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
    
    Set colInstalledPrinters = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Printer where Name = '" & myName & "'")
    For Each myPrinter In colInstalledPrinters
        myPrinter.SetDefaultPrinter
        Exit For
    Next
    
    Set SelectAPrinter = Printer
      
End Function
```

Comment: thank you so much for that solution! Yes I can live with the slight of having to temporarily set the default printer. I'll probably wind up getting tasked with tracking down why all those redirects and multiples occur (not from our code) in windows and then this exercise will be moot. But the need is now for this solution and you sir have helped me fill the need!! .

Answer (score 1):

You can use a helper method to "cast" the object to a Printer.  However, the helper method does use the Printers collection:

```
Private Function SelectAPrinter(myName As String) As Printer
   Dim MyWMIService As Object
   Dim MyPrinters As Object
   Dim MyPrinter As Object
   
   Set MyWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")
   Set MyPrinters = MyWMIService.ExecQuery("Select Name from Win32_Printer where Name = '" & myName & "'")
   
   For Each MyPrinter In MyPrinters
       Set SelectAPrinter = FindPrinter(MyPrinter.Name)
       Exit For
   Next
End Function

Private Function FindPrinter(ByVal DeviceName As String) As Printer
   Dim p As Printer
   
   For Each p In Printers
      If UCase(p.DeviceName) = UCase(DeviceName) Then
         Set FindPrinter = p
         Exit For
      End If
   Next
End Function
```

Comment: unfortunately the Printers collection has been rendered useless for us with that client. For the moment this solution wont work for me. Or course I'll bet my bottom dollar I get  tasked with solving the hundreds of redirects and multiples problem. But that's another story.....thank you for offering something just the same.